# passing value from database to jquery using zend framework

Tags: jquery, google-maps, zend-framework

i have this code for google map in my page..i wanted to change the value of the longitude and latitude..it should be from my database..how will i accomplish it?

```
$(function() { 
    demo.add(function() {
        $('#gmap').gmap({'center': '47.660937,9.569803', 'zoom': 10,'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
            var self = this;
            self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {});    
                    }});
    }).load();
});
```

here's when how i declare my variable from database..

```
$propertyId = $this->_getParam('propertyId', null);

            $propDetail = $propertyDb->getProperty($sessionOutlet, $propertyId);

            $this->view->description = $propDetail[0]['Description'];
            $this->view->propertyname = $propDetail[0]['PropertyName'];
            $this->view->longitude = $propDetail[0]['Longitude'];
            $this->view->latitude = $propDetail[0]['Latitude'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the JS variable declaration from ZEND, you can insert PHP variable in your JS code like this :

```
var longitude = <?php echo $this->longitude; ?>; // for number
var description = "<?php echo $this->description; ?>"; // for string
```

You could also use inline conditional :

```
var myVar = "<?php echo (isset($this->myVar)) ? $this->myVar : 'Not defined' ; ?>"
```